# Why isn't my multivalue converter working?

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I can't figure out what I'm missing. I'm using a multivalue converter that takes in a list of Points, sends them to a separate class to be scaled to fit in my ItemsControl, then puts them in a PointCollection to be used as the Points in my polyline. I continually get an error stating:

```
System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException
  HResult=0x80131501
  Message='Set property 'System.Windows.Data.Binding.Converter' threw an exception.' Line number '136' and line position '47'.
  Source=PresentationFramework
  StackTrace:
   at System.Windows.Markup.XamlReader.RewrapException(Exception e, IXamlLineInfo lineInfo, Uri baseUri)
   at System.Windows.Markup.XamlReader.RewrapException(Exception e, Uri baseUri)
   at System.Windows.FrameworkTemplate.LoadTemplateXaml(XamlReader templateReader, XamlObjectWriter currentWriter)
   at System.Windows.FrameworkTemplate.LoadOptimizedTemplateContent(DependencyObject container, IComponentConnector componentConnector, IStyleConnector styleConnector, List`1 affectedChildren, UncommonField`1 templatedNonFeChildrenField)
   at System.Windows.FrameworkTemplate.LoadContent(DependencyObject container, List`1 affectedChildren)
   at System.Windows.StyleHelper.ApplyTemplateContent(UncommonField`1 dataField, DependencyObject container, FrameworkElementFactory templateRoot, Int32 lastChildIndex, HybridDictionary childIndexFromChildID, FrameworkTemplate frameworkTemplate)
   at System.Windows.FrameworkTemplate.ApplyTemplateContent(UncommonField`1 templateDataField, FrameworkElement container)
   at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.ApplyTemplate()
   at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore(Size availableSize)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(Size availableSize)
   at System.Windows.Controls.Canvas.MeasureOverride(Size constraint)
   at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore(Size availableSize)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(Size availableSize)
   at MS.Internal.Helper.MeasureElementWithSingleChild(UIElement element, Size constraint)
   at System.Windows.Controls.ItemsPresenter.MeasureOverride(Size constraint)
   at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore(Size availableSize)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(Size availableSize)
   at System.Windows.Controls.Border.MeasureOverride(Size constraint)
   at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore(Size availableSize)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(Size availableSize)
   at System.Windows.Controls.Control.MeasureOverride(Size constraint)
   at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore(Size availableSize)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(Size availableSize)
   at System.Windows.Controls.Canvas.MeasureOverride(Size constraint)
   at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore(Size availableSize)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(Size availableSize)
   at System.Windows.Controls.Border.MeasureOverride(Size constraint)
   at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore(Size availableSize)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(Size availableSize)
   at System.Windows.Controls.Grid.MeasureCell(Int32 cell, Boolean forceInfinityV)
   at System.Windows.Controls.Grid.MeasureCellsGroup(Int32 cellsHead, Size referenceSize, Boolean ignoreDesiredSizeU, Boolean forceInfinityV, Boolean& hasDesiredSizeUChanged)
   at System.Windows.Controls.Grid.MeasureOverride(Size constraint)
   at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore(Size availableSize)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(Size availableSize)
   at System.Windows.Controls.Border.MeasureOverride(Size constraint)
   at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore(Size availableSize)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(Size availableSize)
   at System.Windows.Controls.Grid.MeasureCell(Int32 cell, Boolean forceInfinityV)
   at System.Windows.Controls.Grid.MeasureCellsGroup(Int32 cellsHead, Size referenceSize, Boolean ignoreDesiredSizeU, Boolean forceInfinityV, Boolean& hasDesiredSizeUChanged)
   at System.Windows.Controls.Grid.MeasureOverride(Size constraint)
   at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore(Size availableSize)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(Size availableSize)
   at MS.Internal.Helper.MeasureElementWithSingleChild(UIElement element, Size constraint)
   at System.Windows.Controls.ContentPresenter.MeasureOverride(Size constraint)
   at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore(Size availableSize)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(Size availableSize)
   at System.Windows.Controls.Border.MeasureOverride(Size constraint)
   at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore(Size availableSize)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(Size availableSize)
   at System.Windows.Controls.Page.MeasureOverride(Size constraint)
   at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore(Size availableSize)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(Size availableSize)
   at MS.Internal.Helper.MeasureElementWithSingleChild(UIElement element, Size constraint)
   at System.Windows.Controls.ContentPresenter.MeasureOverride(Size constraint)
   at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore(Size availableSize)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(Size availableSize)
   at System.Windows.ContextLayoutManager.UpdateLayout()
   at System.Windows.ContextLayoutManager.UpdateLayoutCallback(Object arg)
   at System.Windows.Media.MediaContext.FireInvokeOnRenderCallbacks()
   at System.Windows.Media.MediaContext.RenderMessageHandlerCore(Object resizedCompositionTarget)
   at System.Windows.Media.MediaContext.RenderMessageHandler(Object resizedCompositionTarget)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.TryCatchWhen(Object source, Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate catchHandler)
   at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.InvokeImpl()
   at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.InvokeInSecurityContext(Object state)
   at MS.Internal.CulturePreservingExecutionContext.CallbackWrapper(Object obj)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at MS.Internal.CulturePreservingExecutionContext.Run(CulturePreservingExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.Invoke()
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.ProcessQueue()
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.WndProcHook(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
   at MS.Win32.HwndWrapper.WndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
   at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.DispatcherCallbackOperation(Object o)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.TryCatchWhen(Object source, Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate catchHandler)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.LegacyInvokeImpl(DispatcherPriority priority, TimeSpan timeout, Delegate method, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
   at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.SubclassWndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
   at MS.Win32.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessage(MSG& msg)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrameImpl(DispatcherFrame frame)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrame(DispatcherFrame frame)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.Run()
   at System.Windows.Application.RunDispatcher(Object ignore)
   at System.Windows.Application.RunInternal(Window window)
   at System.Windows.Application.Run()
   at CADViewer.App.Main()

  This exception was originally thrown at this call stack:
    [External Code]

Inner Exception 1:
InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'CADViewer.Converters.ListToPointCollectionConverter' to type 'System.Windows.Data.IValueConverter'.
```

Can anyone explain to me what this error is telling me? I've tried searching it but nothing seems to apply to my case. Why does it think I'm using an IValueConverter? Thanks in advance for any help you can give.

Here is my Converter:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Media;

namespace CADViewer.Converters
{
    public class ListToPointCollectionConverter : IMultiValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            var points = (List<Point>)values[0];
            var extents = (List<double>)values[1];
            var canvasWidth = (double)values[2];
            var canvasHeight = (double)values[3];

            if (points == null)
            {
                return null;
            }

            var collection = new PointCollection();
            
            foreach (Point point in points)
            {
                Point canvasPoint = DXFToCanvas.DXFCoordToCanvas(point, extents, canvasWidth, canvasHeight);
                collection.Add(canvasPoint);
            }
            return collection;
        }

        public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the relevant XAML:

```
<Page.Resources>
        <j:ListToPointCollectionConverter x:Key="ListToPointCollectionConverter"/>
        <j:CenterConverter x:Key="CenterConverter"/>

        <Style TargetType="{x:Type TabPanel}">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Black"/>
        </Style>
    </Page.Resources>

  <Canvas Background="Transparent"
                    ClipToBounds="True"
                    SizeChanged="ViewportSizeChanged"
                    MouseLeftButtonDown="ViewportMouseLeftButtonDown"
                    MouseLeftButtonUp="ViewportMouseLeftButtonUp"
                    MouseMove="ViewportMouseMove"
                    MouseWheel="ViewportMouseWheel" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1"
                    HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"
                    Width="900" Height="500">

                    <ItemsControl x:Name="MapPageItemsControl"
                               Width="900" Height="500">

                        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                <Canvas Background="Transparent" Width="900" Height="500"/>
                            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>

                        <ItemsControl.Resources>
                            <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:CanvasPolyline}">
                                <Polyline x:Name="polyline" Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="0.5">
                                    <Polyline.Points>
                                        <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource ListToPointCollectionConverter}">
                                             <Binding Path="{Binding DxfVerteces}"/>
                                            <Binding Path="{Binding Extents}"/>
                                            <Binding Path="{Binding CanvasWidth}"/>
                                            <Binding Path="{Binding CanvasHeight}"/>
                                        </MultiBinding>
                                    </Polyline.Points>
                                </Polyline>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ItemsControl.Resources>

                        <ItemsControl.RenderTransform>
                            <MatrixTransform x:Name="transform"/>
                        </ItemsControl.RenderTransform>

                    </ItemsControl>
                </Canvas>
```

Comment: The four inner bindings look wrong to me. The Path should be a property path, not sure what `{Binding DxfVeteces}` is but probably not a property path. Also, these are for sure not properties of the `Polyline` element.

Comment: Have you considered a viewbox for this scaling? Perhaps a drawing/visual brush.

Comment: @KlausGütter I think I've got a fundamental misunderstanding of how this binding works. How would you set the values to a different class? For example, I've got a class called CanvasPolyline and I'm attempting to bind to a property of it called DxfVerteces.

Comment: @Andy I haven't tried that. Are there some benefits of doing it that way over how I've done it?

Comment: You could just build to a known size and scale everything using the viewbox. Seems like it'd be way simpler to me.

Comment: @Andy I'll check it out. Do you have any ideas to why it's attempting to cast my converter into IValueConverter? I have it inheriting from IMultiValueConverter so I'm very confused why it would even be giving me errors for IValueConverter.

Comment: When you do elementname you're saying properties of that control

Comment: Them properties don't exist.

Comment: As the CanvasPolyline is the DataContext here, just write `<Binding Path=DxfVerteces/>` etc. (without ElementName). You could also consider to add a property `public PointCollection Points` to the `CanvasPolyline` class and bind directly to it, without the MultiValueConverter.